# Integrate Algolia to WordPress site

Tags: plugins, search

Algol released this on their website:
https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress

Which is supposed to allow us to integrate it to a wordpress site.

However, I don't understand how am I supposed to do it. Should I just zip the algoliaplugin.php and add it as a regular plugin ?

As anyone ever tried to implement it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a normal plugin. You can install it by doing the following:

- On the Github Page click "Download Zip" button on the right side.
- On your WordPress admin panel navigation to Plugins
- Click "Add New" button at the top of the page which will take you to the "Add Plugins" page.
- Click "Upload Plugin" button at the top which will allow you to upload and install the entire zip file as a plugin. ( WordPress will unpackage it for you )

After that you will be prompted to activate the plugin, if not you can go to Plugins page and manually activate the plugin. Simple as that!

Unfortunately, I can't say I've ever implemented this on any of my sites but it looks like they have decent documentation on how to use it. Specific questions regarding the plugin would probably be better suited to the developers themselves @ the [support section](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/issues).